# How do I auto-size a React Material Slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I set an auto-width for the slider? All I can do is set a fixed width in the css, or leave it blank, in which case it ends up being zero width.

I need to have the label on the left (as big as it needs to be without wrapping), and then the slider next to it, which reacts as it's container changes shape. Thanks:

```
   <FormControl style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row' }}>
  
            <FormControlLabel
                value="Slider"
                control={  <Slider
                  value={sliderValue}
                  min={0}
                  max={1}
                  step={0.01}
                  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                  onChange={handleSliderChange}
                  getAriaValueText={valueLabelFormat}
                  valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
                />  }
                label="Slider:"
                labelPlacement="start"
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) to 1 in the child of a flex container to make it expand.

```
<FormControl sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
  <FormControlLabel
    value="Slider"
    sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    control={<Slider valueLabelDisplay="auto" sx={{ mx: 3 }} />}
    label="Slider:"
    labelPlacement="start"
  />
</FormControl>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]